# How to merge master branch in to feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging

So Initially I had REPO (Let's say ABC_123) which contains bunch of sub-components, those components' branch name was given (Let's say DEV). FYI, ABC_123 repo's ~/.repo/manifest.xml contains all these sub-components' name and their branch name i.e. "DEV".

I needed to fork a branch/repo for some misc development, so I created a snapshot of ABC_123 and give it a name of XYZ_123 which again taken a snap-shot of all those sub-components' from branch "DEV" and I gave new branch name "FEATURE". so, now XYZ_123 repo's ~/.repo/manifest.xml contains all these  sub-components' name and their branch name i.e. "FEATURE".

So, REPO(ABC_123) ==> clone to ==> REPO(XYZ_123)
        BRANCH_name(DEV) ==> clone to ==> BRANCH_name(FEATURE)

> Both above REPO and BRANCHES exist in REMOTE server (so, it is not just locally created branches or repo)

Now, I want to regularly keep merging changes from DEV branch to FEATURE branch, so my feature branch doesn't get out-dated.

How do I fast-forward my feature branch to master branch? I want to retain commit history of incoming changes as result of fast-forwarding.

Thanks,
Krunal

I have looked around the stackoverflow, most of the questioned those being discussed have same branch name. I have tried using "git merge" but I would love someone who is git expert can explain my problem's solution.

Comment: have you tried `git pull XYZ_123 DEV` ?

Comment: you mean to say "git pull FEATURE DEV" ??? Does it retain the history of commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks folks for replying,

Here is the answer that I was looking for:

I had following configuration on REMOTE server
1)  REPO(ABC_123) ==> clone to ==> REPO(XYZ_123)
2)  REPO(ABC_123) has all the projects from BRANCH_name(DEV)
    REPO(XYZ_123) has all the projects from BRANCH_name(FEATURE)
3) all above were created on remote server.
4) we need to regularly pull all the changes from ABC_123 to XYZ_123 repo to make sure XYZ_123(our feature branch) never gets outdated to ABC_123(our dev branch).

we pull using these steps:
Task-1) Sync the FEATURE branch first
    1) git clone or REPO INIT/SYNC the XYZ_123(FEATURE BRANCH)
    2) set "origin" URL of each projects
    3) go to each projects of this REPO and perform Task-2)

Task-2)
1) "git fetch origin DEV"
   a) This fetch all the changes from DEV branch pointed by "origin" URL and put it aside
   Note: (name of the branch is "DEV" = our master branch from which we want to bring the change to "FEATURE" branch)
2) "git merge --no-edit --no-ff origin/DEV" 
   b) This will merge Step-1) fetched changes to current branch (FEATURE branch)
3) "git push origin HEAD:refs/for/refs/heads/FEATURE"
   c) This will push the pulled changes to FEATURE branch in form of gerrit.